# Decision Making at API gateway Integration Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a API gateway connected to SQS service, currently it just forward all the incoming requests bodies to SQS by SendMessage action.
I hope at integration request step I can check if the request has a certain field. If so, return a custom response and do not call the SQS service, otherwise forward the request body to SQS as I am doing right now.

I can do this by using a lambda function triggered by API gateway but i am wondering if I can do this without using lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve that by setting up a request validator on AWS Api Gateway as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-set-up.html)